# Shapes (worksheet) vs. Controls (userform)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a worksheet placed label, but I'd like to dynamically call it by providing name string.

I've tried many suggestions, this one gave me most hope:

[Can I reference an object using a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502199/can-i-reference-an-object-using-a-string)

I have successfully achieved desired effect in the past, but those applications were all userform based. This one has no userforms so apparently I can't use Userform.Controls?

It is suggested to use Shape instead, however whenever I want to change caption of the shape, it says that it doesn't have that property. I've tried "combining" labels and shapes in weird ways, but of course I always got mismatch.

I'm just going to use the example from the linked answer

```
Dim shpLabel As Shape

Set shpLabel = Sheet1.Shapes("labelnum" & i)
shpLabel.Caption = "some string"
```

Apparently this was working for some people (maybe older versions?) but for me it always returns that the property is missing.

I'm hoping I don't have to do something like this:
[Using string as object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339139/using-string-as-object-name)

The main reason why I want to do it this way is speed and size. The file is already very slow and I am concerned that recursive code like that is only going to make it worse.

Comment: What kind of shape is it and how are you adding it?

Comment: Oh, it's label, like in the example, and it already exists. Hundreds of labels and dozens of different actions with each label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little buried and it depends on exactly which type of label it is:

If it's a form control label:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("LabelName").Textframe.Characters.Text = "Some string"
```

If it's an activex control label:

```
Sheet1.OLEObjects("LabelName").Object.Caption = "Some string"
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the ActiveX version that worked. I have to remember this one.

Comment: @JohnT just be aware that ActiveX will not run under **Office** 64-bit. So in the future you may see some errors pop up.

Comment: @L8n given the fact that my project exists of many ActiveX controls on Office 64-bit with multiple machines using it, I determine that to be a false statement

Comment: @TimStack My answer was based on problems we've encountered and this [Microsoft Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261#32or64Bit=Office_2013). For the 2013 Version they explicitly state ActiveX Components as source of problems (that can be worked around), in later versions of the Office Environment this seems to be resolved. So yes, the general statement seems to be false, but I would still keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Michael's excellent answer:

The following `Function` enables you to easily rename the caption of a label, whether it is an ActiveX or Form control object.

```
Function changename(shapename As String, newname As String, workbookname As String, sheetname As String)
With Workbooks(workbookname).Sheets(sheetname)
    If .Shapes(shapename).Type = 12 Then
        Set shp = .OLEObjects(shapename).Object
        shp.Caption = newname
    Else
        Set shp = .Shapes(shapename)
        shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = newname
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Then you can call it as follows

```
Sub ChangeShapeCaption()

changename "Label1", "The caption has changed", "Book1", "Sheet1"

End Sub
```

Comment: No need to pass `ActiveX As Boolean` as boolean. You can check the type of shape using `Shp.Type`. If it is form control then `Shp.Type = 8` else if it is ActiveX control then `Shp.Type=12`

Comment: Even better @SiddharthRout, I have edited my answer accordingly